# Why does ANTLR4 take a very long time to build a parse tree for the String class

Tags: antlr4

I am experimenting to build a parse tree for Java's String class using the following standard ANTLR setup code block. I am using the standard Java8.g4 grammar published on the antlr4 repository (The complete code is available at https://github.com/cagdasgerede/whysolong).

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);

System.out.println("Building the parse tree...");
long start = System.nanoTime();
ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
long elapsedNano = System.nanoTime() - start;
long elapsedSec =
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedNano, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
System.out.println(String.format(
    "Built the parse tree...(took %d seconds)", elapsedSec));
```

The output is:

```
Building the parse tree...
Built the parse tree...(took 21 seconds)
```

I tried to run several times and I see that it takes more than 20 seconds.
Is it normal that it takes this long? Am I doing something wrong in my setup? Is there a way to speed the build of the parse tree up?

To observe the issue on your computer, please execute these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/cagdasgerede/whysolong
cd whysolong
make
```

Comment: Try a second run and don't measure the first (which includes a lot of warmup, which costs time). Do things change for the better then?

Comment: I need a more technical suggestion.